# Как подключать данные заново

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Я пишу тесты, мне нужно в `beforeEach` каждый раз обновлять переменную `mw`. Это глобально доступный синглтон. Из него берутся все данные окружения для тестов. Внутри теста я их хочу подменять.

Файл mw.js

```js
export var mw = {
  config: {
    r: {},
    get: (arg) => {
      return mw.config.r[arg]
    }
  },
}
```

```js
let mw = require('./mw').mw // на самом деле глобальная
mw.config = 'test'

console.log(mw.config) // test

mw = require('./mw').mw
console.log(mw.config) // test
console.log(require('./mw').mw.config) // test
```

Почему это так работает? Как сделать так, чтоб при каждом выполнении функции данные подхватывались заново?

Мне нужно подменять некоторые данные для тестов и точно не хочется заводить 50 файлов, отличимые одной строчкой.

Может быть есть какой-то другой правильный способ проводить такие тесты?

Comment: `let mv1 = require('./mv').mv;

let mv2 = require('./mv').mv;

console.log(mv1==mv2)`

Если выполнить этот код, то окажется что это один и тот же объект

Comment: Дело видимо в том что функция require кэширует модуль mv, и потому при повторном вызове require('./mw'), она возвращает тот же объект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед повторным вызовом модуля 'mw', вы должны удалить его из кэша

```
let mw = require('./mw').mw // на самом деле глобальная
mw.config = 'test'

console.log(mw.config) // test
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./mw')];
mw = require('./mw').mw
console.log(mw.config) //""
console.log(require('./mw').mw.config) //""
```

Как вариант в функции beforeEach сразу копировать объект `let mw = Object.assign({}, require('./mw').mw);`

Comment: копировать не вариант, потому что даже библиотеки типа deepAssign не умеют копировать глубоко зарытые методы у объектов.